# javascript questions about keyword this

Tags: javascript, firebug, this

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function init() {
        var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var nodeArr = [];
        for( var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) // Copy NodeList to Array
            nodeArr.push(nodeList[i]);
        for( var i = 0; i < nodeArr.length; i++) // Loop over array
            if( nodeArr[i].className == "clickLink" )
                nodeArr[i].onclick = clickLink2;    // Attach event function
    }

    window.onload = init; //Attach event function

    function clickLink2() { 
        console.log("this: " + this); //Prints window URL in href
        console.dir( this ); //show attributes of anchor    
        console.log( this.name ); // Prints name attribute
    }


    function clickLink( elem ) {
        console.log( "this: " + this ); //Prints [object Window]
        console.dir( this ); // Shows attributes, etc. al of [object Window]
        console.log( "name: " + elem.name );    
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- inline -->
    <a href="#" name="blah1" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 1</a>
    <a href="#" name="blah2" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 2</a>
    <a href="#" name="blah3" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 3</a>
    <a href="#" name="blah4" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 4</a>


    <hr/>
    <!-- not inline -->
    <a href="#" name="blah5" class="clickLink">Test 5</a>
    <a href="#?t" name="blah6" class="clickLink">Test 6</a>
    <a href="#" name="blah7" class="clickLink">Test 7</a>
    <a href="#" name="blah8" class="clickLink">Test 8</a>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I did the testing in firefox, with firebug to view the console output.

Now what I was wondering:

1. Why in `clickLink` does *this* refer to the window object?
2. Why does *this* in `clickLink2` print to console as the value of the href of the link?
3. Is there a better way to pass *this* to an unobtrusive attachment like this? how can you be sure what *this* refers to?

OK, so I took pieces from the answers here and found that *this* is a bit quirky in some browsers.  Also that assigning a function to `onclick` is different then attaching (but unfortunately not all IE versions support that either see `addEventListener` vs `attachEvent`).  For some reason older IE's also make *this* inside the body of an event trigger function still refer to the window object instead of the caller.  So I used `event.srcElement`.  Here's some new sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function init() {
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var nodeArr = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) // Copy NodeList to Array
        nodeArr.push(nodeList[i]);
    for( var i = 0; i < nodeArr.length; i++) // Loop over array
    if( nodeArr[i].className == "clickLink" ) {

        var a = nodeArr[i];

        if (a.addEventListener) {  //IE9, other browsers
            a.addEventListener('click', clickLink2);    // Attach event function
        } else if (a.attachEvent) { //IE6,7,8, etc.
            a.attachEvent('onclick', clickLink2 ); // Legacy IE Attach event function
        }           

        a.onclick = function() { return false };   // override default onclick behavior for these anchors so URL is not followed
    }
}

window.onload = init; //Attach event function

function clickLink2() {

    if( typeof(event) != 'undefined' ) {
        elem = event.srcElement; //IE < 8 keeps this as window object   
    } else {
        elem = this;    
    }

    alert( elem.name );
}


function clickLink( elem ) {
    alert( elem.name );
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- inline -->
<a href="#" name="blah1" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 1</a>
<a href="#" name="blah2" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 2</a>
<a href="#" name="blah3" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 3</a>
<a href="#" name="blah4" onclick="clickLink(this); return false;">Test 4</a>


<hr/>
<!-- not inline -->
<a href="#" name="blah5" class="clickLink">Test 5</a>
<a href="#?t" name="blah6" class="clickLink">Test 6</a>
<a href="#" name="blah7" class="clickLink">Test 7</a>
<a href="#" name="blah8" class="clickLink">Test 8</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to read about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: You are passing a referens to the current element `onclick="clickLink(this)` and receiving it in `function clickLink( elem )` as `elem`. Why not use that one?

Comment: @Stefan The code I present wasn't really meant to do anything specific, just to try to figure out what the keyword _this_ was doing in different situations.  Combined with zzzzBov's MDN link, the explanations of those below, and my own tinkering I think I have a better handle on _this_ in Javascript now. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why in clickLink does this refer to the window object?
Put simply: clickLink isn't the event handler, by adding the attribute `onclick` to the elements, you're using the native `onclick` method as a handler that calls a function. this function is declared in the main scope, thus this points to the window object. 
To be clear: the behaviour is similar to this:

```
<p onclick='function(){window.clickLink(this);}'>
```

Making the actual event handler an anonymous function, not clickLink. That's why this will point to window: the annonymous function, too, was declared in the global scope, thus the caller of clickLink is window.

2) Why does this in clickLink2 print to console as the value of the href of the link?

Think about this phrase 'Javascript allows you to manipulate the DOM, the DOM-tree, all events and behaviours.' In your init function, the elements onclick behaviour is manipulated. the default method of `onclick` is being overruled, and replaced by the `clickLink2` method here `nodeArr[i].onclick = clickLink2;`.

Look at it like this: all your elements have a prototype onclick method, that accepts a parameter. In the first case, this parameter is a string, that evaluates to a call to the `clickLink` function. The second case, however, the instances that have a particular class have their own onclick method, overruling the prototype's onclick.

I do hope this clears things up a bit for you. It's easy once you grasp the basic philosophy behind events, handlers, methods, prototypes etc... and overcome the quirks of JS.

3) Is there a better way to pass this to an unobtrusive attachment like this? how can you be sure what this refers to?

Well, sort of answerd that above, didn't I? but anyhow: if you define a method of an element or object yourself, in general, this will point to the owner object/element. If you rely on html and default behaviours, JS will mostly mind it's own business and this will point to window.

<strike>I don't know if this is an option, but maybe you could try something like this:</strike>

```
<a onclick='clickLink'>
```

this should -in theory- do the same thing as your init function

**Edit:**
A *working* alternative to the above:

```
<p onclick='clickLink.call(this)'>
```

Call defines the `p` element as the caller of clickLink, making this point to the element that called the function.

Comment: `<a onclick='clickLink'>` doesn't actually work.  The `onclick` attribute is not called like a function, it's supposed to contain code that gets ran.  `<p onclick='function(){window.clickLink(this);}'>` does not work either, it should be `<p onclick='window.clickLink(this);'>`.

Comment: You're right, of course, but the `onclick=function(){}` bit was to show why `this` doesn't point to the element in the clickLink function. I hoped it would make it clear that, in the first example `clickLink` was just a function, not a method of the element. wrote this answer without any checking or rereading, so I'm sorry if not everything is as clear as I thought it was :)

Answer (score 2):

When inline event handlers are called, they are ran in the global scope.  That's why `this` is `window`.

When event handlers are actually attached to an element, they are called in the context of that element, just like when running a method that's part of an object.  That makes `this` the element.

For example:

```
function test(){
    console.log(this);
}
test();  // window

var obj = {
    test: test
}
obj.test(); // obj
```

To be sure of what `this` is, you should attach the event handlers using JS (with `element.addEventListener` or `element.onClick`), and not using inline handlers.

Comment: Right, in my example code I explored both inline and dynamically attached event handlers.  I was trying to determine the difference of _this_ between the two methods.  It appears that if I attach a function dynamically via `addEventListener` that _this_ inside the body of the attached function will refer to the caller that raised the event.

Answer (score 2):

This was one of the most amazing things I learnt about JavaScript, coming from a .NET background.

`this`, when used in a method, doesn't refer to a particular object. It refers to the caller, or the object that raised an event that resulted in a call to an event handler.

To answer number 3 of your questions: just copy whatever this refers to to a new variable:

```
var thisThis = this;
//now pass thisThis. Interesting huh? 
//thisThis will not change with the change of the context. 
//this alone is a keyword that changes depending on
//the context: e.g. who is the caller, what object raised the object, etc.
```

Comment: What I was trying to say with #3, was that inline you can pass _this_ no problem as the first argument, such as `elem` in `clickLink`.  The _this_ in the inline `a` refers to the element itself and is stored in parameter `elem`.  Whereas, when I attach a function dynamically such as through `addEventListener` I cannot pass the _this_ in the way I did inline.  Which I guess isn't a problem, since _this_ in the body of the attached function refers to the caller anyways.

Comment: Also, I was wondering, with #2: is it just the case that an `a` tag when printed to console `toStrings` to the value of its `href`?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a variable pointing to the current *scope*. If you execute the following code in the console:

```
var myPackage = {}
myPackage.method = function() {console.log(this)}
myPackage.method()
```

`this` will be pointing to the `myPackage` object (the scope of `method`).

Instead if you try to run the following:

```
console.log(this) // window
```

this (window) is the reference to the current browser’s window the script executes in.

Comment: "scope" has a slightly different meaning in JavaScript. It might not be the best word because it is ambiguous.